# i want to pass html code from angularjs to onsen page or pass an array to js in onsen page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

Here is my code in angular controller:

```
$scope.showClients='<table>';

for (var i = 0; i < data[0].nomBCL.length; i++)
{
    $scope.showClients+='<tr><td>'+data[0].nomBCL[i]+'</td>';
    $scope.showClients+='<td>'+data[0].tmsBCL[i]+'</td></tr>';

    ////   OR
    //$scope.showClients+='<tr><td>'+data[0].nomBCL[i][0]+'</td>';
    //$scope.showClients+='<td>'+data[0].nomBCL[i][1]+'</td></tr>';
}
```

`$scope.showClients+='</table>';`

angular ng-bind-html doesn't work

The other idea that i thinked of it to pass the data through $scope to the html page as 2d array and put  'for' or 'while' in a javascript, but neither this worked.

The data are from mysql database

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` instead.  Don't mix templates and your controller.

Comment: There are rare cases when you have no other choice. In this case I believe you are right, mixing is a bad idea. But if you load some content, like an article or something, from your database via ajax it might be necessary to use ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"does not work" is usually a bad description for a problem.

Do you get a blank result? In that case it might be possible that Angular doesn't want to show the html because it is considered unsafe.

You have to use the $sce service to make your html string safe:

First inject the service into your controller:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
   ...
}
```

Make your string html safe:

```
$scope.showClientsSafe = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.showClients);
```

Now use "showClientsSafe" instead of "showClients".

I think you have to call the trustAsHtml function everytime you assign "showClients" to "showClientsSafe".

Comment: Without a complete controller code it is hard to know what is wrong. Have you included the $http directive in your controller?

Comment: yup, thought so. Try: 

yourApp.controller("LogInController", ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', function($scope, $sce, $http)

Comment: You are a savior... I'm new at this and I was trying to solve it almost 2 days....